# How can I replicate this js Geospatial query in morphia?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

Querying geospatial data in mongodb looks straight forward enough through the shell script, however, I'm trying to replicate some code in morphia (playmorphia).

Get all points within a certain radius, docs say:

```
> center = [50, 50]
> radius = 10
> db.places.find({"loc" : {"$within" : {"$center" : [center, radius]}}})
```

Here's my code in my Peak model:

```
Double[] loc = new Double(2);
// it's set to my [Longitude, Latitude]

List<Peak> peaks = play.modules.morphia.Model.ds().find(Peak.class).field("loc").near(loc[0], loc[1], 10/111.12).limit(50).asList();
```

It works but am I doing something wrong by using the ds().find()? Is there a more elegant way to do this using the model e.g. Peak.find..? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put indexes on geo fields.

Sample code from my project:

```
@Indexed(IndexDirection.GEO2D)
public Double[] geo = new Double[2];


List<User> pharmacist = MorphiaQuery.ds()
.createQuery(User.class)
.filter("isPharmacist",true)
.field("geo")
.within(nelat, nelng, swlat, swlng)
.field("geo")
.near(u.geo[0], u.geo[1])
.limit(limit)
.asList();
```

Check the manual:
http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Query#Geo-spatial

Comment: Thanks for that. I did not realize it was in the utils import com.google.code.morphia.utils.IndexDirection;

Comment: Previously, I did manually index this field through mongodb shell, which is why it worked in the first place. Marking your answer correct because it can help others.

Comment: [The manual is now located here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#geo-spatial)

Answer (score 0):

**@Indexed(IndexDirection.GEO2D)
    public Double[] geo = new Double[2];

```
public static string getResult`enter code here`() {
        DB datastore = ConnectionFactory.getInstance().getDatabaseMongo();
        double[] near = { 20.593684, 78.96288 };
        BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
        basicDBObject.put("type", "Point");
        basicDBObject.put("coordinates", near);
        BasicDBObject geoNearParams = new BasicDBObject();
        geoNearParams.append("geoNear", <collection name>);
        geoNearParams.append("near", basicDBObject);
        geoNearParams.append("spherical", true);
        geoNearParams.append("maxDistance", 100);
        geoNearParams.append("limit", 10);
        CommandResult commandResult = datastore.command(geoNearParams);
        commandResult.getErrorMessage();
        Object data = commandResult.get("results");
        System.out.println(data.toString());
    }**
```